# When is it better to do send data to the client side and filter from the client than to make a server request to search inside the database?

Tags: javascript, database, request

So, by learning more about SQL and database. I end up having a question :

**When is it better to do send data to the client side and filter from the client than to make a server request to search inside the database ?**

We can imagine a shop website where we access a catalogues of products.
We can see all the products and filter them.

By example, I can filter :

- Only vegetables
- More than 1 kilos
- From Venezuela.

**But when is it better to send all my product to the client and filter it when needed ?**  
   **And when Is it better to make a query for each time the user do it ?**

I think DB are more optimize to do the job, but there could be some inconvenient like doing a server request each time.

**So what are the elements I need to look at to know what is the good/best choice in this kind of situation ?**

Comment: This is a bit broad, since a lot of times you can do either without much problem. Good practice would sometimes depend on security reasons (you don't want to send sensitive data to the client and expect the user to not be able to access it), other times it's convenience (easier to filter on the server or the client), other times still it might be down to your stack or your particular application (e.g., implementing a filter on either client or server would be too much work for very little benefit, when it's cheaper to do it on the other side). And it might be a mix of these or other factors.

Comment: If your clients are running on phones with a couple gigs of RAM, you don't want to push 8GB of data to their browser and then filter the data there (not to mention the data charges they'll accrue). But if they're running on high-spec desktops or laptops with 32GB of RAM and fast processors, maybe it makes sense. There are many, many variables to take into account. You can do some research elsewhere on the internet; there are many articles discussing this topic.